# Put a link on AmChart graph

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts, amcharts

I'd like to add a link to the upper-right corner of the chart. The main idea is to have it as responsive as the chart itself and consequently it should always be displayed at that upper-right corner whenever the chart container is resized.

Something like on the screenshot below.

[image]

I've managed to implement it with amchart [Label](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/Label) feature and by usage of custom css classes (don't forget to enable [addClassNames](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmChart#addClassNames) property in order to have such possibility).

The full example of the code you can find by this [**JSFiddle link**](http://jsfiddle.net/9kjh28we/4/).

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "addClassNames": true,
  "titles": [{ "text": "Chart title" }],
  "dataProvider": [... data should be here ],
  ...
  // a lot of unrelevant to question properties
  ...
  "allLabels": [{
    "id": "xx",   /// id which is used for css customization
    "text": "View data",
    "bold": true,
    "x": "90%",
    "y": "3%",
    "rotation": 0,
    "width": "100%",
    "size": 11,
    "align": "middle",
    "url": "http://google.com" 
  }]
});

.amcharts-label-xx {
  text-decoration: underline;  // make the text underline imitating the link
}
```

But I'm looking for **far more native and straightforward way** to do that. Is there so? I don't like the approach I've used because of a lot of hardcoded values (e.g. absolute positions). Probably it can be achieved by usage of [titles and subtitles](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/adding-chart-title-subtitle/) amchart components?

Appreciate any ideas.

Comment: you can user export options available into AmChart if you need to export data. (concluded from your sceen)

Comment: The labels are the only native way to accomplish this within the chart API. The percentage-based positions aren't absolute positions as they will re-position within the chart as the container is resized. You can use the [responsive plugin](https://github.com/amcharts/responsive) to fine-tune the label's positioning based on the width/height of the container.